# Springboot REST API not returning JSON with simple GET request

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I am new to Java and Springboot.
Attempting to implement a simple get request with one parameter, terminalId which is a string.

The Findall() endpoint works fine, but when implementing an endpoint to match with strings I run into trouble.

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/private/v1")
public class TransactionController {

    private TransactionService<TransactionResponse> transactionService;

    public TransactionController(TransactionyService<TransactionResponse> transactionService) {
        this.transactionService = transactionService;
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @GetMapping(value = "/transactions")
    public List<TransactionResponse> retrieveTransactions(){
        return transactionService.findAll();
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @GetMapping(value = "transactions/{terminalId}")
    public List<TransactionResponse> retrieveByTerminalId(
            @PathVariable String terminalId) {
        if (terminalId != null) {
            return transactionService.findByTerminalId((terminalId));
//            @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Service

```
    List<T> findAll();

    List<T> findByTerminalId(String terminalId);

    T save(T object);
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class TransactionServiceImpl implements TransactionService<TransactionResponse> {

    protected List<TransactionResponse> transactionResponseList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public List<TransactionResponse> findAll() {
        return transactionResponseList;
    }

    @Override
    public List<TransactioResponse> findByTerminalId(String terminalId) {
        return transactionResponseList;
    }

    @Override
    public TransactionResponse save(TransactionResponse object) {

        if(null != object){
            transactionResponseList.add(object);
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

Bootstrap Component

```
@Component
public class TransactionBootstrap implements CommandLineRunner {

    private TransactionService<TransactionResponse> transactionService;

    public TransactionBootstrap(TransactionService<TransactionResponse> transactionService) {
        this.transactionService = transactionService;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData() {

        TransactionResponse response1 = new TransactionResponse("111", LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now());

        TransactionResponse response2 = new TransactionResponse("222", LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now(),);



        transactionService.save(response1);
        transactionService.save(response2);

    }
}
```

I am using ths "localhost:8080/api/private/v1/transactions/111" URL

I get a whitelabel error page.
Is this a JPA issue?
Is this a @RequestParams vs @PathVariable issue?

I am totally lost.

Comment: It's a path variable, any server console exception when you access GET localhost:8080/api/private/v1/transactions/111 ?

Comment: You have missed a `/` for api which is failing. Check your GetMapping value.

Comment: @Suman, i don't think its due to the ``/``. @Dustin, can you elaborate on your error? are you getting 404 or something else? Can you post what are you seeing as the response?

Comment: @gtiwari333 It's 404 error, type Not Found. for a URL localhost:8080/api/private/v1/transactions/111

Comment: Can you try if  ```/api/tr/2``` following works for below controller? I suspect its due to some other config. Can you share your code on github?

```@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Ctrl{
    static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("AAA");
    @GetMapping(value = "/tr")
    public void a() {
        log.warn("a");
    }
    @GetMapping(value = "tr/{id}")
    public void b(@PathVariable String id) {
        log.warn("a" + id);
    }
}```

Comment: my guess is that your problem is because you have two endpoints called `/transaction`. Spring doesn't know if you are calling the first or the second without any argument. It's just a guess but try renaming the second one and see if it works then.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed / in @GetMapping(value = "transactions/{terminalId}")

Write @GetMapping(value = "/transactions/{terminalId}")